# Is it OK for Scrapy's request_fingerprint method to return None?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to override Scrapy's default [RFPDupefilter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) class as follows:

```
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter

class URLDupefilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        if not request.url.endswith('.xml'):
            return request.url
```

The rationale is that I would like to make the `requests.seen` 'human-readable' by using the scraped URLs (which are sufficiently unique) rather than a hash. However, I would like to omit URLs ending with `.xml` (which correspond to sitemap pages).

Like this, the `request_fingerprint` method will return `None` if the requests URL ends with `.xml`. Is this a valid implementation of a dupefilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into `request_seen()` method of `DupeFilter` class you can see how scrapy compares fingerprints:

```
def request_seen(self, request):
    fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
    if fp in self.fingerprints:
        return True
    self.fingerprints.add(fp)
    if self.file:
        self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
```

`fp in self.fingerprints`, in your case this would resolve to `None in {None}`, since your fingerprint is `None` and `self.fingerprints` is a `set` type object. This is valid python and resolves properly.
So yes, you can return `None`.

Edit: However this will let through first `xml` response, since the `fingerprints` set will not have `None` fingerprint in it yet. Ideally you want to fix `request_seen` method in your dupefilter as well to simply return `False` if fingerprint is `None`.