# TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' in Scrapy's dupefilter

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running a scraper with a `JOBDIR` (cf. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) such that crawls can be paused and resumed. The scraper has run successfully for a while, but now when I crawl the spider I get logs which end with the following:

```
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml> (referer: None)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml> (referer: None)
scraper_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
scraper_1  |     yield next(it)
scraper_1  | GeneratorExit
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_errorcount)
scraper_1  | Exception ignored in: <generator object iter_errback at 0x7f4cc3a754c0>
scraper_1  | RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
scraper_1  | {'downloader/request_bytes': 306,
scraper_1  |  'downloader/request_count': 1,
scraper_1  |  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
scraper_1  |  'downloader/response_bytes': 2498,
scraper_1  |  'downloader/response_count': 1,
scraper_1  |  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
scraper_1  |  'finish_reason': 'closespider_errorcount',
scraper_1  |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 21, 14, 53, 13, 139012),
scraper_1  |  'log_count/DEBUG': 26,
scraper_1  |  'log_count/ERROR': 1,
scraper_1  |  'log_count/INFO': 10,
scraper_1  |  'memusage/max': 75530240,
scraper_1  |  'memusage/startup': 75530240,
scraper_1  |  'request_depth_max': 1,
scraper_1  |  'response_received_count': 1,
scraper_1  |  'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
scraper_1  |  'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 1,
scraper_1  |  'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
scraper_1  |  'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 1,
scraper_1  |  'spider_exceptions/GeneratorExit': 1,
scraper_1  |  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 21, 14, 53, 10, 532154)}
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_errorcount)
scraper_1  | Unhandled error in Deferred:
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
scraper_1  | 
scraper_1  | 2017-06-21 14:53:13 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
scraper_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 517, in _oneWorkUnit
scraper_1  |     result = next(self._iterator)
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 63, in <genexpr>
scraper_1  |     work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 183, in _process_spidermw_output
scraper_1  |     self.crawler.engine.crawl(request=output, spider=spider)
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 210, in crawl
scraper_1  |     self.schedule(request, spider)
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 216, in schedule
scraper_1  |     if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 54, in enqueue_request
scraper_1  |     if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
scraper_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/dupefilters.py", line 53, in request_seen
scraper_1  |     self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
scraper_1  | TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1 exited with code 0
```

It seems like the error is being caused in `dupefilters.py`. I had a look at the source code, https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilters.py, but haven't so far been able to uncover what is causing this error. Any ideas?

**Update**

Here are some more details on how the spider is implemented. It is a `SitemapSpider` as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from apkmirror_scraper.spiders.base_spider import BaseSpider


class ApkmirrorSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider, BaseSpider):
    name = 'apkmirror'
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 0,
        'CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 16,
        'TOR_RENEW_IDENTITY_ENABLED': True,
        'TOR_ITEMS_TO_SCRAPE_PER_IDENTITY': 50,
        'FEED_URI': '/scraper/apkmirror_scraper/data/apkmirror.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'apkmirror_scraper.dupefilters.URLDupefilter',
    }

    download_timeout = 60 * 15.0        # Allow 15 minutes for downloading APKs

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.sitemap_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self._parse_sitemap, dont_filter=True)
```

where the `parse` method is defined in the `BaseSpider` class. I've defined a custom `URLDupefilter` as follows:

```
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter


class URLDupefilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        '''Simply use the URL as fingerprint. (Scrapy's default is a hash containing the request's canonicalized URL, method, body, and (optionally) headers). Omit sitemap pages, which end with ".xml".'''
        if not request.url.endswith('.xml'):
            return request.url

    def request_seen(self, request):
        '''Same as the RFPDupeFilter's request_seen method, except that a fingerprint of "None" is viewed as 'not seen' (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370949/is-it-ok-for-scrapys-request-fingerprint-method-to-return-none).'''
        fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
        if fp is None:
            return False                            # These two lines are added to the original
        if fp in self.fingerprints:
            return True
        self.fingerprints.add(fp)
        if self.file:
            self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
```

However, the error seems to be coming from Scrapy's built-in `RFPDupeFilter` class. I don't understand why this is still enabled if I set `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` to the custom one?

Comment: You shouldn't use `request.url` as fingerprint, because it will not be accurate. For example if you go to page x and it redirects to page y, next request to page y will not be filtered out since your fingerprint is the url of x. There are few more cases like that, that's why you should call super method to generate fingerprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class URLDupefilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        '''Simply use the URL as fingerprint. (Scrapy's default is a hash containing the request's canonicalized URL, method, body, and (optionally) headers). Omit sitemap pages, which end with ".xml".'''
        if not request.url.endswith('.xml'):
            return request.url
```

This will return `None` if request url ends with `.xml`. Then dupefilter tries to write what it thinks is a string to a file, by combining that string with newline character. Since it tries to combine None and a string you get TypeError.

To fix this simply return a string for `.xml` pages:

```
    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        if not request.url.endswith('.xml'):
            return request.url
        return ''
```